# cannot display pdf file in modal window

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display a pdf file in modal window.
HTML

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" href="<?php echo base_url() . 'Users/download/' . $row['markid']; ?>"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">Open Modal</button>
<td>
```

Modal window

```
<?php
if (!empty($files)) {
    foreach ($files as $frow) {

        ?> 
        <div class="modal-body">                     
            <embed src = "<?php echo base_url() . 'uploads/files/' . $frow['file_name']; ?>" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="400px"> 
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Controller

```
public function download($markid = NULL)
{
    $this->load->helper('download');
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    echo $markid;

    $fileInfo = $this->User_Model->getRows($markid);

    $file = 'uploads/files/' . $fileInfo[0]['file_name'];

    force_download($file, NULL);
}
```

I am not able to get the pdf file ? kindly give the solution.

Comment: You forgot to close div after embed tag. Also keeping modal in a loop is not a great idea. Do you have multiple PDF files to show in different modals?

Comment: ...and the `embed`-tag wants a type as well: `type='application/pdf'`. Just a heads up, Chrome on android doesn't support PDF-embeds anymore.